# React-native-reanimated executing external native build for cmake

Tags: react-native, runtime-error, react-native-reanimated

When I install `react-native-reanimated` in my project after try to run my app it's show me bellow error:

```
Cause: executing external native build for cmake /Users/MyPC/React-Native/Citi-App-Old-version/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/CMakeLists.txt
```

Version of use:

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.8.0",
```

Can you please help me for fixed this error?

Comment: please, provide a sample directory so that me and others can take a deeper look.

Comment: Please provide your gradle build file, as there is likely a conflict with a value defined there, and your actual build environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your React Native version or downgrade Reanimated because even reanimated [2.6.0](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/releases/tag/2.6.0) depends on React Native `0.68` but your version is `0.63`